# sharing sms not working on my window system

Tags: html, reactjs

I tried to use `href='sms:` to share SMS in my react app. this worked fine on my mobile browser test but not working on my window laptop. I keep getting this error message on my console inspect.

> Failed to launch
> 'sms:?&body=Check%20out%20this%20product%20I%20found%20on%20Sabi%20https://tbazesolutions.com.ng/actions/product/11f76e1107sgbdhg'
> because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

```
const shareMessage = `Check out this product i found:`;

SMSShareLink href={`sms:?&body=${shareMessage}${url}`}>
 <TextMessageIcon />
</SMSShareLink>
```

Comment: Hello, can you give us some more details about the behaviour of your components?

Comment: @iSckraa I have a product page with a share button. This share button allows a user to share the URL link via WhatsApp, SMS and copy link. I tried the code above to implement the SMS share and running this share button on mobile browser worked but on my windows chrome I'm getting the failed error message above.